# Javascript - How do I invoke an anonymous method as a variable and access its properties and methods?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, anonymous-function, language-concepts

I've read that we can invoke an anonymous function as a variable. However I'm trying to do that and in addition to it I want to access its properties and methods. Here is my code

```
var cooking = function(){
        this.dessert = "Ice Cream";
        this.numberOfPortions = 20;
        this.doubleLunch = function(){this.numberOfPortions = 40;
            document.write(this.numberOfPortions);};
        };

document.write(cooking.dessert);
```

But I don't get anything. Can you say me what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cooking` is a function. **When you call it**, it defines a number of properties on whatever `this` is.

The structure implies that it is intended to be used as a constructor function, so you would create an instance of it using the `new` keyword.

Then you can interact with the instance.

```
var meal = new cooking();
document.write(meal.dessert);
```

NB: Convention dictates that constructor functions (and only constructor functions) should be named starting with a capital first letter, so you should rename it to Cooking.

Comment: There's also absolutely no point in assigning it to a variable. Just `function Cooking() { ... }` makes more sense.

Comment: Which also assigns it to a variable. In general I would recommend a function declaration over an anonymous function expression though.

Comment: @Quentin  Thank you for answer, but why is it necessary to create an instance of it. For example when I execute <var sum = function(a,b){document.write(a+b);}
sum(3,4);> it shows me the number 7. Is it because this function is different from my first one?

Comment: Umm. Yes. It is different. The big important difference is described in the first paragraph of the answer.

Comment: I understand that the main reason is the way I declare my anonymous function isn't it? But the <var sum = function(a,b){document.write(a+b);} > is still being a Function-Object?

Comment: "I understand that the main reason is the way I declare my anonymous function isn't it?" — No. It is because the purpose of the function is to define properties on whatever `this` is.

Comment: Then if I don't use this then my first function would be the same as the secod? I used "this" because I wanted to declare properties of a function-object. Am I wrong? Are there other ways without using "this"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91672/discussion-between-gnirut-and-quentin).

Comment: "Which also assigns it to a variable". Well, the function object will be accessible in a similar manner that a variable would be, but I'd attribute that more to the "everything's an object" part of javascript rather than it "being a variable". The hoisting is entirely different when assigning it to a variable or declaring it as a function. And there's no point in manually assigning it to a variable unless you specifically want it not to be hoisted. Also especially confusing if it's to be used as a "class" since it's an extremely non-standard way of declaring a "class" function.

Answer (score 1):

`this` references to itself when the function is invoked as a constructor which you can do by using an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE).

```
var cooking = (function () {
    return new function () {
        this.dessert = "Ice Cream";
        this.numberOfPortions = 20;
        this.doubleLunch = function () {
            this.numberOfPortions = 40;
            document.write(this.numberOfPortions);
        };
    }
})();

document.write(cooking.dessert);
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/fk4uydLc/1/**

However, you can achieve the same result by using a plain old JavaScript object (POJO).

```
var cooking = (function () {
    var obj = {};

    obj.dessert = "Ice Cream";
    obj.numberOfPortions = 20;
    obj.doubleLunch = function () {
        obj.numberOfPortions = 40;
        document.write(obj.numberOfPortions);
    };

    return obj;
})();

document.write(cooking.dessert);
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/vmthv1dm/1/**

If you plan on using the constructor multiple times then the approach @Quentin mentioned is the way to go.

```
function Cooking() {
    this.dessert = "Ice Cream";
    this.numberOfPortions = 20;
    this.doubleLunch = function () {
        this.numberOfPortions = 40;
        document.write(this.numberOfPortions);
    };
}

var cooking = new Cooking();

document.write(cooking.dessert);
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/jsd3j46t/1/**

Comment: thanks for the answer. I make the same appointment as in the other answer. Why is it necessary to create an instance of it. For example when I execute <var sum = function(a,b){document.write(a+b);} sum(3,4);> it shows me the number 7. Is it because this function is different from my first one?

Comment: because of `this`. `this` refers to itself only when it's an instance, which why you need to use `new`. Otherwise `this` is the outer scope, in this case the `window` object. http://jsfiddle.net/jsd3j46t/

Comment: I'm using "this" because I wanted to declare properties of a function-object. Am I wrong? Are there other ways?

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one question: Is <var sum = function(a,b){document.write(a+b);} > still being a function object?

Comment: @GniruT not entire sure what you mean. All functions are objects. `var foo = function() {}` is a function expression. `function foo() {}` is a function declaration. `function Foo() {}; new Foo()` is a function invocation and the returned object is the instance.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I thought a function is an object or not depending of its declaration. Now I understand it :)